# Implementing a search algorithm android

Tags: java, android, search

Hi I would like to a search for a file on my androids SD Card .Preferably without using the File Object if possible.Is it possible to query the MediaStore for a filename. Any code snippet or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @NotAUserNot Yet,Would like to know the best possible way first.

Comment: @kalz there is no best possible way, all depends on situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Media Provider already has all the files info, so it's better to directly query Media Provider for this.

Something like below:

```
      String where = FileColumns.DATA + " like " + "XYZ";

      cursor =    Context.getContentResolver().query(Files.getContentUri("external"),
                        projection, // Which columns you need
                        where, null
                        }, null);
```

This to just give u a idea; please modify it according to your need. Hope it help's.

Comment: Nice one Munish. Thanks for the input.Time to get my hands dirty.